# Is it possible to have multiple server connections with signalr in the browser?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, signalr

**Question**

I'm using signalr to do the usual stuff in my application and now I need to attach to another hub on another domain too ... is this possible?

Specifically I need to be able to have two separate connections, to two different URLs, open simultaneously.

**Details**

So imagine i'm running my web application @ https://example.com and in that application I have a few hubs that the app can use.
At this point everything is standard signalr as you might see in Microsofts own getting started guides for the framework.

Along comes "the real world" and now I need to connect to a hub @ https://api.example.com in the javascript code running on pages in the same web app hosted @ https://example.com.

Is this possible?
Is this a good idea?
Should I be doing something else?

The documentation seems to imply but never explicitly states that signalr can only be used to connect to the application that the page came from.

**The technical bit**

These scripts are already on my page and talking back to the main app ...

```
<script src="~/scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

I tried adding this ...

```
<script src="https://api.example.com/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

and then began writing the init code but realised that `$.connection` was a bit of an unknown to me but i assume would always refer to https://example.com on the other end.

What i need is a second connection that goes to the api domain but how?

Comment: try setting `$.connection.hub.url` . You might also run into CORS issues, though, there are a few links to suggestions if you google signalR CORS

Comment: wouldn't that just invalidate / break the first connection so I could use the second?

Comment: oh ok, it wasn't clear from your wording that you wanted to have two connections to different URLs open simultaneously

Comment: Yeh it's hard to explain ... sorry about that ... if you can think of better wording feel free to edit :)

Comment: I suppose I could create a "proxy hub" in the main app and have that subscribe to the api one somehow ... I wonder if that would be better.

Comment: Done. Just added it to the opening section as a clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect to hubs outside your page. This is even stated and exampled in [SignalR Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#crossdomain). As a pre-caution, the server must have CORS enabled, or else it will throw CORS errors in your JS.

To start working with multiple connection on the client side you would do something among the lines of:

```
var connection = $.hubConnection("http://www.api.endpoint.com");
var apiHub = connection.createHubProxy('apiHub');

apiHub.client.foo = function() { // event function };

connection.start();
```

As a pre-caution (another), Chrome has a limit of (I believe) 5 simultaneous connections, and this varies from browser to browser. So if you have a lot of requests open at the same time, eventually some of them might fail. Edit: I suspect this applies to simultaneous connections of the same origin.

[SignalR Documentation - How to establish a connection
 (That I used for example)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#establishconnection)

Comment: oooo nice catch ... i didn't know you could just tell SignalR to make a new connection like that (i guess i missed that subtle part of the docs).